# Is it possible to add custom functionality to a delphi component to be triggered if a specific key is pressed?

Tags: delphi, custom-component

On my application I have several TDbLookup components and on everyone of them I have to add a procedure that closes and then open again the lookup Query, on the Key Press Event.

So I was wondering:

How can I customize a descendent of TDbLookup component, in order to have a boolean property available on Object Inspector, that I can enable to accomplish this?

If set to true, with focus on the TDbLookup , pressing F5 key, closes and then open the lookup query again.

Is it possible?

Comment: You don't need to derive a new control. You can handle that with KeyPreview in the form. Basing all your forms on a common ancestor allows you to centralise the policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Derive a new component from `TDbLookup`, add your desired property, and then override the virtual `KeyPress()` method to look at that property and act accordingly.